# Install swap files instead of swap partition manually in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, swap

Read a lot of pages in the arch linux wiki, and finally I'll install the OS, the problem is that they have a large collection of commands that I don't understand (the prefixes are illegible) so I made a text file like a cook recipe for the installation.

```
loadkeys la-latin1
iw dev
wifi-menu -o [iw dev output device name]
cfdisk
lsblk
mkfs -t ext4 dev/sdaX
/* here comes the swap part */
mount dev/sdaX /mnt
swapon xxx
pacstrap /mnt base base-devel grub-bios networkmanager os-prober
genfstab -U -p /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab
...
..
.
```

The thing is that I want to use swap files instead of swap partition, because I hate that messy swap table with windows. 
I read a [post](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/swap#Swap_file) of swap in the arch linux but I think needs a re check because I couldn't understand it at all, what is `chmod 600`?. Are the steps in right order?, 
And I don't trust the "automated method". 
How do I make a swap file just with the / folder, what lines should I add to the txt

Comment: If you're asking about swap files, what do the commands you presented here have to do with it? Except for `swapon`, none of them look like they're related.

Comment: @ilkkachu in the line `/* here comes the swap part */` I don't know the order of the wiki commands. it's like adding that part to the txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several steps to setting up a file to use as swap space.

1 - make the file.  Several ways, I use `dd` to read from `/dev/zero` and output to a file - `dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/swapfile bs=1024 count=100000`  will create a 1gb file.  Once the file is created, set the mode to 600 - `chmod 600 /path/to/swapfile` and make sure that the root user is the owning user.

This `dd` command - `if` is the input file, /dev/zero in this case.  `of` is the output file, where is the data being written to?  In this case, it is the full path to our swap file.  `bs` is block size, we want to grab 1024 bytes at a time, and `count` tells us how many to get (enough to make 1gb in this case)

2 - make the file a swap file system `mkswap /path/to/swapfile`

Once that is done, you can manually start it up when needed with `swapon /path/to/swapfile` or if you want it to always be active, put a reference in your /etc/fstab to load it

```
/path/to/swapfile    none     swap     sw     0    0
```

Just be sure you add the line AFTER the line to load whatever filesystem the swap file actually lives on

Comment: for what is the `count` parameter? `dev/zero` is the target of the partition wich I want to put the swap file isnt it?

Comment: @RenatoA. - editing answer to clarify

Comment: could be `bs=1M count=1024`?

Comment: `fallocate` made a 4GB file immediately on a weak device: `fallocate -l 4G /swapfile`.`https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-a-swap-file-on-an-arch-linux-cloud-server